# Redirect specific subdirectories inside a subfolder only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Using `.htaccess` I am successfully redirecting a specific set of subfolders ( *blog*, *dev*, *media*, etc ) to subdomains.

Like so:

> `www.website.com/_subs/dev/foo` gets directed to `dev.website.com/foo`

This has been achieved with the following fragments of code:

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website.com
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/_subs/blog/(.*)$
> RewriteRule .* http://blog.website.com/%1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website.com
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/_subs/dev/(.*)$
> RewriteRule .* http://dev.website.com/%1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website.com
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/_subs/media/(.*)$
> RewriteRule .* http://media.website.com/%1 [R=301,L]
> ```

The question is:

> **How do I prevent access to the `/_subs` folder if a request ISN'T made to one of my specific subfolders?**

I would like any requests being made to `www.website.com/_subs/foo` to simply be redirected to `www.website.com`

I have tried using a 301 redirect along with various other attempts to no avail :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules are a lot more complicated than they need to be and I think that's making the solution harder to see.

Here's what I came up with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteRule ^_sub/(blog|dev|media)/?(.*)$ http://$1.website.com/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteRule ^_sub(/.*)$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301]
```

The `RewriteCond`s limit the first two rules so that they only run on `website.com` and `www.website.com`.  Presumably you might have a url like `http://blog.website.com/_sub/this-rocks` in the future that you don't want redirected.

Including both domains in the first rewrite means you will have one less 301 redirect, which should make a request to http://website.com/_sub/blog redirect directly to http://blog.website.com much faster.  The L makes sure that nothing that matches this rule will get marked as forbidden.

The second rewrite returns 403 for anything starting with `/_sub` that is not matched by the first rule.  The `/` is inside the group so that this will match `/_sub`, `/_sub/`, and `/_sub/.*`.  If the `/` were outside you would not be able to 403 `/_sub` without a separate rule.

The last rewrite is the same as your very first rule - there is no need to put the L, though, as it's already the last rule to process.